# Angular custom orderBy that combines alphabetical and numerical sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array as follows (data simplified for the question):

```
var myArray = ['Text 1', 'Text 9', 'Text 10'];
```

Understandbly the regular Angular orderBy yields the below when applied:

```
Text 1
Text 10
Text 9
```

I am looking for the most elegant way to write a custom orderBy function that will produce:

```
Text 1
Text 9
Text 10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write custom expression for orderBy filter like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = ['Text 1', 'Text 9', 'Text 10'];
    
    $scope.myExpression = function(item) {
        var words = item.split(' ');
        return parseInt(words[1]);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in myArray | orderBy:myExpression">
      <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what if `Text` is different?

Comment: Thanks!  This gave me what I needed.  I simplified the question a bit as myArray can also be text without numbers that needs to be sorted alphabetically but not a mixture of the two (i.e. all elements either have numbers or none do).  I used your myExpression though and just added a isNaN check that simply returns item if there is no number.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what data you may have. If it can be only 'Test x' where x is number:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in data | orderBy: ['length', 'toString()'] track by $index ">{{obj}}</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EfwZL55YgrHrDANLXwtO?p=preview